# Como obter o múltiplo de algum valor em PHP?

Tags: php, matemática

Preciso fazer uma busca no banco de dados e de acordo com o valor encontrado dentro de uma faixa de valores deve retornar um valor específico.

Por exemplo: se encontrar os valores de 1 a 4, deve retornar 1, encontrando de 5 a 8, deve retornar 2.

É preciso o múltiplo de determinado valor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O que você precisa é da função [**ceil()**](https://www.php.net/ceil), que arredonda valores para cima.

Assim você pode usar:

```php
$valorRetornado = ceil($seuValor / 4);
```

Por exemplo:

```php
echo ceil(1 / 4);     // dá 1
echo ceil(4 / 4);     // dá 1
echo ceil(5 / 4);     // dá 2
echo ceil(8 / 4);     // dá 2
echo ceil(54654 / 4); // dá 13664
```